# Request just a section of file via backgroundtranferapi

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Is there any way to request for just a section of file manually while using background transfer apis. I want to achieve something similar to multi-thread downloading.

Comment: Could you please detail your question? What are you actually doing, downloading or uploading? How you split your files currently?  Any actual  issues when you using the background transfer API?

Comment: I'm downloading the file! I just wanna grab a section of file, say the first megabyte of it. If this functionality used with other features on the top of it will boost the speed very drastically like many of the win32 apps do.

Comment: However when creating a new downloading with background transfer api, it doesn't seems like there is a mechanism for requesting just a section of file by maybe using custom get request

Comment: Yes, no APIs of background transfer could do this directly. Please try to use HTTP relative APIs.